# Screen error: Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module)

Tags: linux, perl, gnu-screen

I'm new to linux coding and have just been given an account on a server at work. I don't have sudo permissions. For some unknown reason, the 'screen' program has suddenly stopped working. Every time I try to open a screen session I get the following error

Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/user/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/user/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/user/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/user/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

I've tried opening up my .bash_profile and .bashrc to delete any lines referring to perl or the local::lib, and I don't have permissions to install the local::lib myself. I've tried navigating to the directories listed in the error message but they also don't exist. I also tried reinstalling perl and screen into a conda environment but screen needs to be activated before the environment so I just got the same message. Both perl and screen are still installed as I can print the version.

I have no idea why screen suddenly stopped working as I don't think I did anything, and it was working perfectly fine for the first few weeks. Any ideas/help would be much appreciated!

Comment: local::lib is a third-party library not bundled with perl by default. Its purpose is to help manage the local installation/use of third-party modules within the user's home directory under ~/perl5/. The idea is that local::lib iteself and anything else gets installed under ~/perl5/, and suitable PERL5LIB environment variable is set so that ~/perl5/ is searched.

Comment: It probably stopped working because either the ~/perl5/ directory went away / was emptied and/or the PERL5LIB environmant variable stopped being set. See [link](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib)

Comment: @DaveMitchell ~/perl5/ is still present in my home directory with the .modulebuildrc file (but nothing else). Do I need to reset the PERL5LIB environment variable and if so, how do I do this? I read the link you sent me and tried the three things suggested but none worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See @dave-mitchell's comments to what `local::lib` is, but as for how to solve the problem, you'll probably need to install local::lib yourself in your home directory. This does not require administrative access using the bootstrap method as outlined in the local::lib documentation:
https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#The-bootstrapping-technique

Following that, cpanminus ([cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus)) should be able to install most perl modules using the `--local-lib` option as needed.

However, if this is simply a problem with screen itself not working, and you don't care about perl modules per se, then I would recommend installing `tmux` as an alternative to `screen` which is also possible to do without administrative privileges ([see this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1259140/how-to-install-tmux-locally-without-root-access)) and is widely considered to be a superior option